# Want Suggestion on Automating Software Installation Project

Tags: c#

I am making program to automate software installation in C#.
 I hooked mouse & keyboard to listen events performed while setup installs..
 First Admin needs to install program which need to be mass installed on connected clients.
 So admin runs Server which hooks mouse & keyboard events while perticular installation of software & admin selects unique screen region for screenshot to later matched on client installation process to determine whether specific form has arrived, only then simulate key or click else wait until screenshot matches..(eg.next form came after clicking on Next Button only then simulate click or Keystrokes)

Correct me if i am wrong..plz..

1) Well i know same thing can be possible with Group policy object but it can only install msi packages not the exe setups... so they need to be converted to msi first.. i googed free programs for this conversion but none are free. ( All free programs are just simple exe to msi converters but that converted msi still ask clients something while installing if any error condition is there) & ofcource u need to purchase windows Server licence for domain controller pc's this will not possible for Indian Schools,Cybercafe's,Charitable Trusts..

2) There is no free program to do this task perfectly AutoIT,AutoHotkey tries it well but not every time it succeeds.

3) White Framework on Codeplex is nice but still hangouts sometimes while installing..

So this way is ok? or there is any other way to do this ( i want to automate exe,msi ondemand unattended installation)

Answer (score 0):

Pertaining to #2, you are indeed incorrect. AutoIt is perfectly capable of handling this, in fact one of the basic AutoIt examples is an Installer (tutorial here: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/82288-installer-creator/)

With a bit of tweaking you could turn that into a great installer, with much less effort than it would take in C#

Maybe if you could tell us exactly what problems AutoIt has been causing you?